# What does "earn their paychecks" mean in the following newspaper excerpt?

Tags: meaning

The nation and the world would be better off if Congress took a break from partisanship and finally debated a legal framework for the American military action .... Republican lawmakers prefer to simply blame President Obama rather than earn their paychecks.

Comment: Do the work they're being paid to do.  It's part of the job of the US Congress to form US foreign policy, including its military actions.  Simply blaming the President isn't doing that job.

Comment: The idea is that public servants are hired by the nation to do their jobs. They are the nation's employees. The nation is the employer. When they're not doing their jobs, they get their money for nothing. Earning one's paycheck means doing something one was hired to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of "lawmakers", they would "earn their paychecks" by doing what they're paid to do, passing laws; here, they would do that by making laws that provide a "legal framework" for military action.